# Entity Framework Find second query that is invoked in parallel

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, async-await

I know, that parallel query execution is not supported in Entity Framework. Now I ran into the issue, that there is a parallel call detected by EF. I already had a look into the documentation mentioned within the exception message: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913. Anyways I couldn't find the code part that is making the first request.

I've tried to:

- go through the warnings if there is one that says there might be an async call
- intercept the queries with a DbCommandInterceptor to log the unfinished one or hit a breakpoint when an execution occurs with a context instance, that already sent one (all were finished when the exception happened)
- checking if all context function calls with name **Async were directly awaited
- Looking in the parallel stacks window to see if I can find a reference to my context

Does anyone have a good approach how to find the code which executes the first query?

I am using EF Core 7.0.0 with SQL Server, Dotnet 6.0 Web API (MVC) and in my Services setup I used:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(c =>
        {
            var connection = Configuration.GetSection("Database").GetSection("ConnectionString").Get<string>();
            c.UseSqlServer(connection, opt =>
            {
                opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(3);
            });
            c.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
                c.EnableDetailedErrors();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked down the requests to the DbSets by using:

```cs
   public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
#if CTX_COLLISION_DEBUG
        internal class TracingInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
        {
            private static List<MyDbContext> _isReading = new List<R4DbContext>();

            public TracingInterceptor(MyDbContext dbContext)
            {
                DbContext = dbContext;
            }

            public MyDbContext DbContext { get; }

            private void Track(string type, bool end)
            {
#if COLLECT_SET_GETS
#else
                StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
                var ownedFrame = stackTrace.GetFrames().Where(f =>
                (
                    (f.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Assembly?.FullName?.Contains("MyDataLib") ?? false)
                    ||
                    (f.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Assembly?.FullName?.Contains("MyServerLib") ?? false)
                )
                && typeof(MyDbContext) != f.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType);

                Console.WriteLine($"Started tracking: {type} from '{DbContext.InstanceId}' @ {string.Join("\r\n", ownedFrame.Select(f => $"{f.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Name}.{(f.GetMethod()?.Name ?? "??")}()"))}");
#endif
                if (end)
                    _isReading.Remove(DbContext);
                else
                {
                    if (_isReading.Contains(DbContext))
                    {
                    }
                    _isReading.Add(DbContext);
                }
            }

            public override InterceptionResult<DbCommand> CommandCreating(CommandCorrelatedEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbCommand> result)
            {
                StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
                var frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(2);
                Console.WriteLine($"T: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} CommandCreating called by: {frame?.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType}.{frame?.GetMethod()?.Name}");
                return base.CommandCreating(eventData, result);
            }

            public override InterceptionResult<int> NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
            {
                Track(nameof(NonQueryExecuting), false);
                return base.NonQueryExecuting(command, eventData, result);
            }

            public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> NonQueryExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                Track(nameof(NonQueryExecutingAsync), false);
                return base.NonQueryExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
            }

            public override int NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, int result)
            {
                Track(nameof(NonQueryExecuted), true);
                return base.NonQueryExecuted(command, eventData, result);
            }

            public override ValueTask<int> NonQueryExecutedAsync(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, int result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                Track(nameof(NonQueryExecutedAsync), true);
                return base.NonQueryExecutedAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
            }

            public override DbDataReader ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, DbDataReader result)
            {
                Track(nameof(ReaderExecuted), true);
                return base.ReaderExecuted(command, eventData, result);
            }

            public override ValueTask<DbDataReader> ReaderExecutedAsync(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, DbDataReader result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                Track(nameof(ReaderExecutedAsync), true);
                return base.ReaderExecutedAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
            }

            public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
            {
                Track(nameof(ReaderExecuted), false);
                return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
            }

            public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                Track(nameof(ReaderExecutedAsync), false);
                return base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
            }

            public override object? ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, object? result)
            {
                Track(nameof(ScalarExecuted), true);
                return base.ScalarExecuted(command, eventData, result);
            }

            public override ValueTask<object?> ScalarExecutedAsync(DbCommand command, CommandExecutedEventData eventData, object? result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                Track(nameof(ScalarExecutedAsync), true);
                return base.ScalarExecutedAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
            }

            public override InterceptionResult<object> ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result)
            {
                Track(nameof(ScalarExecuting), false);
                return base.ScalarExecuting(command, eventData, result);
            }

            public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<object>> ScalarExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                Track(nameof(ScalarExecutingAsync), false);
                return base.ScalarExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
#endif
        public virtual int ID_LENGTH => 30;

        public ShortGuid InstanceId = ShortGuid.NewGuid();
        public ILogger<R4DbContext> Logger { get; }

        public R4DbContext(DbContextOptions options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(options)
        {
            ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
            Logger = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<R4DbContext>>();
        }

#if CTX_COLLISION_DEBUG
    public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.NonPublicConstructors | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicFields | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.NonPublicFields | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicProperties | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.NonPublicProperties | DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.Interfaces)] TEntity>()
    {
#if COLLECT_SET_GETS
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var ownedFrame = stackTrace.GetFrames().Where(f => 
        (
            (f.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Assembly?.FullName?.Contains("R4") ?? false) 
            || 
            (f.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Assembly?.FullName?.Contains("us") ?? false)
        ) 
        && typeof(R4DbContext) != f.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType);

        Console.WriteLine($"Served Set<{typeof(TEntity).Name}> from '{InstanceId}' @ {string.Join("\r\n", ownedFrame.Select(f => $"{f.GetMethod()?.DeclaringType?.Name}.{(f.GetMethod()?.Name ?? "??")}()"))}");
#endif
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new TracingInterceptor(this));
#endif
```

This gave me the parallel calls like:

```
Served Set<Affiliate> from '85y5VJAZNkWSEtUaYU_FIw' @ EntityRepository`1.get_Set()
{a lot of callstack infos}
T: {ThreadID} CommandCreating called by: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateDbCommand
Served Set<Affiliate> from '85y5VJAZNkWSEtUaYU_FIw' @ EntityRepository`1.get_Set()
{a lot of callstack infos}
T: {Other ThreadID} CommandCreating called by: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.CreateDbCommand
```

Then I looked up the Contexts by their generated Id and found the first call on the same Context.

Maybe not the best way to find it, but at least one.